# Keras Xception model input shape confusion

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm reading the docs [here](https://keras.io/applications/) which says that input shape has to be `(299,299,3)` if I specify `include_top=True`. However, if I set `input_shape=None` (where the input shape is really `(32,32,3)`) the model trains. So why is it that this is working?

> input_shape: optional shape tuple, only to be specified if include_top
>   is False (otherwise the input shape has to be (299, 299, 3). It should
>   have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and height should be no
>   smaller than 71. E.g. (150, 150, 3) would be one valid value.

Minimal example:

```
batch_size = 32
epochs = 2

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.xception import Xception


NUM_CLASSES = 10

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, NUM_CLASSES)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, NUM_CLASSES)

print("x_train shape:", x_train.shape) # (50000, 32, 32, 3)


"""
Why does this work when input_shape=None, when the documentation specifies that
input_shape for this model must be greater than 71x71?
"""
model = Xception(weights=None, include_top=True, classes=NUM_CLASSES, input_shape=None)


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_datagen.fit(x_train)

model.fit_generator(train_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

the keras documentation is so clear:

> input_shape: optional shape tuple, only to be specified if include_top is False (otherwise the input shape has to be (299, 299, 3). It should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and height should be no smaller than 71. E.g. (150, 150, 3) would be one valid value.

Answer (score 0):

From Keras document:

The default input size for this model is 299x299 and input_shape default is None.
If include_top is True you can use data with width and height smaller than 71.

Comment: I don't think that's what it says. It says if `include_top=True` it must be (299,299,3), otherwise, it must be greater or equal to (71,71,3)

Comment: In my opinion, it says if include_top=False the input shape has to be (299, 299, 3).... According to, "include_top: whether to include the fully-connected layer at the top of the network."

Comment: `only to be specified if include_top is False (otherwise the input shape has to be (299, 299, 3)` It says to specify if it's False, otherwise (if True) don't specify because it's assumed to be (299,299,3).